# Where should user input be validated: GUI and/or API?

Tags: api, validation, user-interface, user-input, code-duplication

I have a dialog widget with line edits for the user to input necessary data. When OK button is pressed, I call some API to perform necessary action based on inputs. This API that I call can also be called independently of the dialog, i.e. from command line.

Now, in my dialog code, before calling the API, I validate the user input and pop up a message box in case of any error. But, since the API can be called independently, I perform this validation in the API too.

This smells like trouble. What is the correct way to do this?